# Text highlighting and cross-reference warning in Vim LaTeX with harvard.sty on MikTex 2.9

Tags: vim, latex, syntax-highlighting, bibtex, binary-search-tree

I used Vim LaTeX for six months with natbib and had no problems. But to use a new bib style file (i.e., rfs.bst) I started using harvard.sty, which gives me two minor problems:

(1) syntax highlighting is not complete; specifically for `\citeasnoun`, Vim only highlights the `\cite` portion. With another Vim plugin (Vim-plugin-R) I can update the syntax highlighting, but I can't figure out how to do this in Vim. I refreshed the databases in MikTex, but that didn't work.

(2) Vim LaTeX is automatically rerunning as necessary to get references correct -- the status window in Vim shows it going through several runs and the results are as desired -- but I still get this warning:

```
|| LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

How can I fix these? Thanks!

Comment: There are cases in which you cannot get rid of this warning. For example, if inserting the reference _just_ pushes the labelled object to another page, but fixing the reference makes it jump back to its original page.

Comment: @Thomas -- Thanks! Good to know. Do you think that could happen even if everything goes smoothly with natbib and plainnat? This paper is still just a skeleton (<2 pages).

Comment: <2 pages means just 1 page? Then no, this could not happen, and your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Thomas -- 1.3 pages? :)

Comment: Fair enough, if you take a scissor to your PDF file to cut off the last 0.7 page that TeX sticks on :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the syntax highlighting issue, you could try the following.

In your personal vim settings folder -- typically `$HOME/.vim/` on Unix-based systems, or `C:\Users\<yourname>\vimfiles` (?) on Windows (probably the first entry shown in `:set rtp?`), create a directory (if there isn't one already) called `after`, and create a subdirectory of it called `syntax`, and in it create a file called `tex.vim`. So the file will be `$HOME/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim` for Unix or `C:\Users\<yourname>\vimfiles\after\syntax\tex.vim` on Windows. (I hope a Windows user will confirm this, since I'm on Linux.)

In that file, put the following line:

`syn match  texRefZone '\\citeasnoun\%([tp]\*\=\)\=' nextgroup=texRefOption,texCite`

Then when you open a LaTeX file, `\citeasnoun` should be treated just like `\cite` as for Syntax Highlighting (...that's assuming you're using the default Syntax Highlighting rules for LaTeX files that came with vim 7.3 anyway....)

I think your other question is answered in the comments.

Comment: Thanks! That is the correct directory structure. I am still working on the rerun warning.

Comment: I tried using the `g:Tex_IgnoredWarnings` variable in my `_vimrc` file, but didn't have any luck -- my Vim didn't know what those variables were. I'll keep searching. Thanks for your help!

Comment: FWIW, I had to change `g:Tex_IgnoredWarnings` and `g:Tex_IgnoreLevel` in the `texrc` file. I couldn't get the `+=` and `.=` tricks to work, which implies that `texrc` is read before `tex.vim`.